# Bootstrap Material Design table alignment issues

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-material-design

For a website I'm using [Bootstrap Material Design](http://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/) and having a hard time aligning elements in a row (`course.name` and the `course.update`, `course.delete` buttons).

I want them to align vertically with CSS but `vertical-align:middle` doesn't work. Neither does `<tr valign="middle">`.

Any help is appreciated.

```
{% if course_list %}
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tr>
            <th>Course Name</th>
        </tr>
        {% for course in course_list %}
            <tr>
                <td><a class="text-nowrap" href="{% url "courses.detail" course.id %}">{{ course.name }}</a>
                    {% if course.instructor == user %}
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            {% url 'courses.update' pk=course.id as url %}
                            {% bootstrap_button button_type='link' content='Edit' button_class='btn-warning' href=url %}
                            {% url 'courses.delete' pk=course.id as url %}
                            {% bootstrap_button button_type='link' content='Delete' button_class='btn-danger' href=url %}
                        </div>
                    {% endif %}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all your table is not responsive, to make it responsive do structure like this

```
<div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
       //rest of your code
         </table>
     </div>
```

it will make your table responsive and

```
.table td {
   text-align: center;   
}
```

or

```
<td class="text-center">some text</td>
```

make it center aligned